# Classification tree that can fetch more than 1 prediction per observation

Tags: r, classification, data-mining, decision-tree, rpart

I'm searching for an algorythm from the classification trees algorythm familiy,
that can provide a number (more than 1) of predicitions (in some ranked order) per observation.
To be more specific - I have 10 binary target models to predict a target variable with 10 levels. How can I combine the models in such way to fetch a predefine number of prediction with a confidence level. For instance, I want my "combined" model to fetch 2 predictions for each obeservation. Once possible approach is to take the 2 binary models with the highest accuracy for that specific observation and fetch them. How do I calculate the "averaged" accuracy of this set of 2 predictions ?
If anyone can provide literature and R code examples from rpart package, that would be more helpful.
thanks

Comment: Most trees I know will return the posterior probability for each class. Will that do?

Answer (score 0):

in the rpart documentation of predict.rpart:  type = c("vector", "prob", "class", "matrix")

use like:

```
predict(${some r part model}, type="prob")
```

it will give you a vector of the probability of each class

Comment: @user3424107 you can edit your question... you shouldn't post updates in the comments section